# Error type mismatch on value of the defined range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting error type mismatch on the rng.value under objie.document. What I wanted to do is to conduct Google news search based on the value of the defined range and loop through each cell.

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objie As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objie = New InternetExplorer
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    user = Environ("username")
    objie.Visible = True
    For Each cell In rng
    rng.Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    objie.Navigate "https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=(fraud)&tbm=nws&spf=1495542183367&cad=h"

    Do While objie.Busy = True Or objie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    objie.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = _
    rng.Value & " (fraud)"

    Set form = objie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
    Set button = form.getElementsByTagName("button")(0)
    button.Click
    Do While objie.Busy = True Or objie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    TimeOutWebQuery = 5
    TimeOutTime = DateAdd("s", TimeOutWebQuery, Now)
    Do Until objie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
        If Now > TimeOutTime Then
            objie.Stop
            GoTo ErrorTimeOut
        End If
    Loop
    objie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    Call PDFPrint("C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop\" & "Screening_" & rng.Value & " " & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & ".pdf")
ErrorTimeOut:
    Set objie = Nothing
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.cells.Count` is greater than one. That means you cannot access the property value of the range. You have to get at a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rng.cells.Count` is greater than one. That means you cannot access the property value of the range. You have to get at a single cell. You probably mean

```
objie.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = _
cell.Value & " (fraud)"
```

Comment: you're right. didn't catch that. But the problem now is it doesn't go through the loop. It just perform the first cell but doesn't move on to the next cell.

Comment: This seems to be a second problen then. You got a type mis-match in  `objie.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value =  rng.Value & " (fraud)"` Now you get another error. The issue here is the line `Set objie = Nothing` which removes the reference to IE in the loop.

Comment: I already knew and fix that. edited all rng.value to cell.value. it actually runs with the first cell but doesn't do the loop. However, if I run it individual per code (F8), it goes through the next cell or loop but doesn't run the pdf code. weird.

Comment: As said, another issue, just open another post with the fixed code you have so far.